# The offset parameter will be set to NULL if another value is not available what does it mean in php?

Tags: php, arrayaccess

I am learning to **ArrayAccess** interface for my final year project. I don't know when the **offset** parameter of the **ArrayAccess::offsetSet()** is set to **NULL**. As stated in the **php.net**.

> Note: The offset parameter will be set to NULL if another value is not
>   available, like in the following example.

```
<?php
$arrayaccess[] = "first value";
$arrayaccess[] = "second value";
print_r($arrayaccess);
?>
```

> The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first value
    [1] => second value
)
```

So what is the concept of **NULL** here ? Can anyone tell ?

Reference Link http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetset.php.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned ArrayAccess, this is interface, and if you implement that in your class - you will be able to use your class as array.

You copied sentence from manual about offsetSet method

> Note: The offset parameter will be set to NULL if another value is not available, like in the following example.

Example is not really correct there, so I prepare another one:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/baedfadc9bd6bbfbde5ef7152e8c4e7d4a1d99e2

output is:

```
this is MyTest::offsetSet offset: NULL; value: 'first value'
this is MyTest::offsetSet offset: NULL; value: 'second value'
```

You can see that offset parameter is NULL if you do not set it in the code, however if you use code like that:

`$arrayOffset[3] = "third value";`

offset parameter will be `3`

**UPDATE:**
Answering on your question:

No. If you want to support both, insertion, and updating. You should implement this logic in `offsetSet` method. e.g:

```
public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
{
    if (is_null($offset)) {
        $this->data[] = $value;
    } else {
        $this->data[$offset] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, first parameter will be null if you do not set it in code.
In php array syntax, if you do not set offset basically it means ` array_push($array, "your value"); `, you did not provide offset, that's why it NULL

Comment: And during the insertion offset will be assigned in the array according to the location, instead of Null, yes ?

Answer (score 2):

As we've learned, the `offsetSet()` method of the `ArrayAccess` interface provides the logic needed to handle *assignment* of a value to an *offset* of the object that implements `ArrayAccess`:

```
public function offsetSet($offset, $value) 
{
     if ($offset === null) { 
         echo "Offset is NULL!"; 
     } else {
         echo "You assigned '$value' to '$offset'."; 
     }
}
```

When we specify a key to assign a value to an offset of an `ArrayAccess` object, PHP passes the key to `offsetSet()`:

```
$arrayAccess['name'] = 'Alex'; 
// Outputs: "You assigned 'Alex' to 'name'."
```

However if we don't provide a key, PHP sets the value of the first parameter of `offsetSet()` to `null`:

```
$arrayAccess[] = 'Alex'; 
// Outputs: "Offset is NULL!"
```

This syntax is similar to how an array performs a *push* operation when no offset is specified:

```
$array = []; 
$array[] = 'Alex';
```

When we implement the `offsetSet()` method of the `ArrayAccess` interface, we can choose to mimic this behavior, or we could perform a different behavior, such as throwing an exception if we don't want to support an empty offset. `ArrayAccess` objects don't necessarily *need* to copy the behavior of arrays.

Comment: So it means that if no offset is assigned, the offsetSet() first parameter offset will receive the NULL ? But during the insertion into the array the offset will be assigned according to the location of insertion instead of NULL? ha?

Comment: @MummyDaddy Yes, that's correct. `ArrayAccess` lets us choose if we want our object to behave like `array` when the offset is empty, or we can make it do something else. See update!

Comment: How can we discriminate the case when we use `NULL` as key? I.e.: `$array[NULL] = 'Bob'` on builtin arrays, NULL as an array key is converted to an empty string `''` and the empty string is used as key, but in the case of the `ArrayAccess` interface it seems that there is no way to tell whether the `offsetSet()`'s `$offset` parameter was explicitly set to `NULL` (NULL key) or not set at all (append). Are you aware of a way to discriminate these 2 cases and implement `ArrayAccess` interface so that it behaves like a standard PHP array? Thank you!

Comment: @tonix Unfortunately, this is a case where `ArrayAccess` does not match the behavior of built-in arrays. There is no way to distinguish between `$a[null]` and `$a[]` in an `offsetSet()` implementation just as there is no way to distinguish between `$a[null]` and `$a['']` for a built-in array. If we must handle `null` offsets, we have to forgo using the `ArrayAccess` shorthand (perhaps by replacing it with class methods that provide "push" and "set" behavior separately).